# gVim / Vim with cvim error every startup on windows 7

Tags: vim, windows-7-x64

I'm using gVim with cvim plugin on Windows 7 x64. Everytime I start gVim, it gives the following error message:

```
"Global template file '.s:C_GlobalTemplateFile.' not readable."
```

I've search google for the error message, and found [this solution](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script:213), but it didn't work. Has anyone found the same problem with this? What's the fix?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
    let s:vimfiles = $VIM
```

change to:

```
    let s:vimfiles = $VIM.'/vimfiles/'
```